# Pandas DataFrame count row length for specific entry

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
     item   color
0   apple     red
1  orange  orange
2  banana  yellow
```

is there a way to count the row length of a specific entry such as "orange"? Not count the entire row length but the len of the particular "item" column. Like I want to write some type of code that would state "orange" is in the second row or second in the index.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying? Do you mean how many observations are in the item column, or do you mean the number of characters in the item column for a particular observation?

Comment: I reedited my post since it was confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking for the location of an item in the Series, you could convert it to a list and then call `.index()`:

```
list(df['item']).index('orange')
```

[image]

You just have to keep in mind that Python is 0-indexed and so the index '1' means it is the second item.